# jQuery-autocomplete add images in result

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I have a project where a user can search for other users from search bar, but using autocomplete, I can only get the username of other users, not there profile pictures. My `users` table has a column `avatar` in which profile picture of every user is stored.
Controller:

```
public function autocomplete1() {
    $queries = User::where(function($query) {
        $term = Input::get('term');
        $query->where('username', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
    })->take(6)->get();
    $results = array();

    foreach($queries as $query) {
        $results[] = ['query' => $query->avatar, 'avatar' => $query->username];
    }
    return response::json($results);    
}
```

View:

```
$(function() {
    $('#text3').autocomplete({
        source: "autocomplete1",
        minlenght: 2,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#text3').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
    $('#text3').data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ui, item) {
        var $li = $("<li style='width:800px; margin-left:10px; margin-bottom:5px'>"),
        $img = $("<img style='width:8%'>");

        $img.attr({
            src: '{{URL::to('/')}}/images/' + item.avatar,
            alt: item.value
        });
        $li.attr('data-value', item.value);
        $li.append("");
        $li.append($img).append("" + item.value);
        return $li.appendTo(ul);    
    };
});
```

Comment: Arg ! Copy-paste your code and properly format it, do not use screenshots :-((

Comment: updated the question @AlFoиceѫ

Answer (score 0):

In your php code it looks like you're only pulling out the `username` from each object (`$v->username`).  Try:

```
$results[]=['value'=>$v];
```

I think this will store the entire object in the array (hopefully with your desired profile picture field).

Comment: i think pulling everything will not work as my table contains around 10 cloumns

Comment: If you really don't want the extra data fields (or they contain sensitive information) you could pull the profile picture field similarly to how username is done. $v->profile_pic (if profile_pic is the property name in your data object)

Comment: i tiried it but it gave me the name of that image instead of showing the image

Comment: NOPE IT JUST RETURNED THE NAME OF THE IMAGE